# Unable to see the created .xlsx file in the directory

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I had generated a few values and had populated them into a spreadsheet using `xlsxwriter`. This is how I did it:

```
class main1():
    .
    .
    .
    .
    def fun1():
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.Output_fold+'Test'+time.strftime("%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y")+'.xlsx')
        worksheet_A = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet_A')
        .
        .
        worksheet_A.write(row,col,<val>)
        .
        .
        workbook.close()
```

Now, since I had to make multiple writes, and added more complex logic, I decided to have another function introduced `fun2` which would write the values accordingly. The new logic requires generating values in `fun1` as well as `fun2` (by calling another function `fun3`). So, I decided to replace variables `workbook` etc with `self.workbook` and likewise. My modified script looks like this :

**main_file.py**

```
import xlsxwriter
import libex
import os
import time
import sys
import string

class main_cls():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i=0
        self.t1=""
        self.t2=""
        pwd=os.getcwd().split('\\')
        base='\\'.join(pwd[0:len(pwd)-1])+'\\'
        print base
        self.Output_fold=base+"Output\\"
        self.Input_fold=base+"Input\\"
        self.workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.Output_fold+'Test_'+time.strftime("%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y")+'.xlsx')
        self.worksheet_A = self.workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet_A')
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i,"Text 1")
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i+1,"Text 2")
        self.i+=1
    def fun1(self):
        self.t1="1"
        self.t2="2"
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i,self.t1)
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i+1,self.t2)
        self.i+=1
        self.eg=libex.exlib()
        self.t1=self.eg.gen(0)
        self.t2=self.eg.gen(0)
        self.fun2()
        self.workbook.close()
    def fun2(self):
        if option==1:
            self.fun3()
    def fun3(self):
        self.t1=self.eg.gen(0)
        self.t2=self.eg.gen(1)
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i,self.t1)
        self.worksheet_A.write(self.i,self.i+1,self.t2)
        self.i+=1

option=int(sys.argv[1])
if len(sys.argv)==2:
    p=main_cls()
    if option==1:
        p.fun1()
    else:
        pass
else:
    print "Wrong command"
```

**libex.py**

```
class exlib():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a="duh"
    def gen(self,x):
        if int(x)==0:
            return(self.a)
        elif int(x)==1:
            self.a=str(self.a+" "+self.a+" "+self.a+" !!!")
            return(self.a)
```

Now, this works in this particular case but in the actual code, it doesn't. The file itself is not getting created in the output directory. Then, I added the following line:

```
    print "Workbook created at path : ",self.workbook.filename
```

to see if the file is getting created and it surprisingly showed with full path!!!

Where could I be going wrong here and how can I get this fixed?

UPDATE1: I played around a bit with it and found that removing `self` from `self.workbook` moving `workbook` to `__init__(self)` creates the file with the initial values populated.

UPDATE2: Have replicated my code in a minimal way as suggested. And this one works pretty well!!!

Comment: It looks like you are opening and closing the file in `fun1()` so it won't be open for writing in `fun2()`

Comment: @jmcnamara Doesn't `self` make it more "global"? I mean just like other variables? Even otherwise, before I write to the excel from `fun2()`, I am writing a few values from `fun1()`. So, in that case, shouldn't it at least show those values?

Comment: I'm mainly commenting on the fact that the workbook is closed in `fun1()` so the call to `write()` in `fun2()` won't have an effect (unless `fun2()` is called from `fun1()`. However, it is hard to judge without seeing the full program. Overall, I think you could save yourself, and us :-), some time by adding a small but complete program.

Comment: I've added some more information up there. Hope that helps. Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: That helps a little but you won't get anything more than guesses until you post a complete working example. See the StackOverflow docs: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, based on your update it looks like you solved the issue.

Comment: @jmcnamara I haven't solved it yet. Just put up my observation. That is, when I removed `self.` from the workbook/worksheet related variables, the `.xlsx` file showed up and the values within same function got filled up. But since `self.` was removed, I couldn't use them to populate from other functions. Have updated the post to show the detailed flow.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to reproduce, file is being created just fine, maybe you have a problem with the self.Output_fold variable, or with file permissions or with your code editor's file explorer.

Comment: I am sure `self.Output_fold` is fine (am printing the path to check the same). The other two - file permissions and code editor's (I'm using pyscripter) file explorer, don't seem to be a problem as well because when I start from scratch and try to reproduce using a minimal code, it actually runs fine just like you said. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.